# Logging laravel logs directly to elasticsearch

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, logging

Currently I am sending laravel logs to elasticsearch via filebeat and logstash,
Is is possible to send laravel logs directly to elasticsearch without filbeat and logstash.

Comment: I explained the details of such an implementations here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67785985/how-to-use-monolog-elasticsearchhandler-for-logging-in-a-laravel-application/67785986#67785986

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [ElasticsearchHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/main/src/Monolog/Handler/ElasticsearchHandler.php) of Monolog.

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#creating-custom-channels-via-factories how to create a custom log channel via factories.

```
composer require elasticsearch/elasticsearch
```

Something like this in your factory:

```
public function __invoke(array $config)
{
    return new \Monolog\Logger(
        $config['name'] ?? 'defaultChannelName',
        [
            new \Monolog\Handler\ElasticsearchHandler(
                // ...
                // see phpdoc of the ElasticsearchHandler::class
            )
        ]
    );
}
```