# Is it possible to get channel name inside custom service provider in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

is it possible to get "name" like "pythons" or "duplicates" of logging channel in boot method inside the custom service provider in Laravel application?

There is a great comment on how to setup elasticsearch with Laravel [How to use monolog ElasticSearchHandler for logging in a Laravel application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67785985/how-to-use-monolog-elasticsearchhandler-for-logging-in-a-laravel-application/77249125#77249125)

e.g. I have two channels defined in logging.php:

```
    'pythons' => [
        'driver' => 'monolog',
        'handler' => ElasticsearchHandler::class,
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
        'formatter' => ElasticsearchFormatter::class
    ],

    'duplicates' => [
        'driver' => 'monolog',
        'handler' => ElasticsearchHandler::class,
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
        'formatter' => ElasticsearchFormatter::class
    ],
```

I would like to have a custom $type instead of using a general one:
$type = config('elastic_log.type');

Thank you.